# Setting click listener on button in Listview row layout

Tags: android, listview, onclicklistener

I have `ListView` as shown in image below

[image]

each white box is a separate `ListView` row. Each `ListView` row has a `Button` at top right corner.

#### what I want

I am trying to set a `OnClickListener` on `Button` of each row. Whenever this `Button` is clicked, i want to delete that row.

The data in each `ListView` row is coming from `Firebase` database. So whenever the cross `Button` is clicked on in any row of `ListView`, i get the value of `Timestamp` and then pass this `Timestamp` as an argument in a separate method that searches in the database for this `Timestamp`. Any key in the `Firebase` database that has this `Timestamp` as its child is deleted.

Method that is used to delete the `ListView` row data is working fine as it deletes the data associated with the `Timestamp` passed in this method as an argument.

#### Problem

Problem is that the `Timestamp` value that i am getting when a button is clicked on any `ListView` is wrong. For example, in the image above, if i click on 2nd `ListView` row with `Timestamp` of `27-01-2018 05-31-22AM`, instead of getting this `Timestamp`, i get the `Timestamp` of the last row of `ListView` and consequently wrong data is deleted.

Here's the relevant code :

**onClick() method**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
        //get the parent view i.e. listview row on which delete button is clicked
        ConstraintLayout listviewRow = (ConstraintLayout) btnDeleteMsg.getParent();

        //get the textview containing receiver username from the view on which delete button is clicked
        TextView textviewReceiver = listviewRow.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgReceiverUsername);

        //get the textview containing timestamp value from the view on which delete button is clicked
        TextView textTimestamp = listviewRow.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgSentTime);

        //get the values of message receiver username and timestamp
        //timestamp value will be used to determine which message to delete
        //from database
        String receiverUsername = textviewReceiver.getText().toString();
        String timestamp = textTimestamp.getText().toString();

        //call delSentMsg() method in SentMessages Fragment using SentMessages Fragment
        //instance passed in the constructor of this class
        sentMsgsFragment.deleteSentMsg(receiverUsername, timestamp);
}
```

**ListView row layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:background="#fff">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_deleteMsg_SMF"
        android:layout_width="17dp"
        android:layout_height="17dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cross_image"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outbox_msgText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/btn_deleteMsg_SMF"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outbox_msgReceiverLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/to_text_label"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/outbox_msgText"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outbox_msgReceiverUsername"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/outbox_msgReceiverLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/outbox_msgText"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outbox_msgDateLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/sent_on_label"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/outbox_msgReceiverLabel"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/outbox_msgSentTime"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/outbox_msgDateLabel"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/outbox_msgReceiverLabel"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@id/outbox_msgDateLabel"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**ListView adapter class**

```
public class CustomOutboxListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{

    private ArrayList<SentMessageTemplate> sentMsgsList;
    private Context context;
    private Button btnDeleteMsg;
    private SentMessages sentMsgsFragment;

    public CustomOutboxListAdapter(ArrayList<SentMessageTemplate> list, Context cont, SentMessages sm){
        this.sentMsgsList = list;
        this.context = cont;
        this.sentMsgsFragment = sm;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.sentMsgsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return this.sentMsgsList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.listview_outbox_messages_row, null);

            //private inner class used to minimize the calls to "findViewById" method
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.datetimeText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgSentTime);
            holder.messageText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgText);
            holder.receiverUsernameText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgReceiverUsername);

            convertView.setTag(holder);

            //click listener for delete button
            btnDeleteMsg = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_deleteMsg_SMF);
            btnDeleteMsg.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        SentMessageTemplate stu = sentMsgsList.get(position);
        holder.datetimeText.setText(stu.getTimestamp());
        holder.messageText.setText(stu.getMessageContent());
        holder.receiverUsernameText.setText(stu.getMsgReceiver());

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //get the parent view i.e. listview row on which delete button is clicked
        ConstraintLayout listviewRow = (ConstraintLayout) btnDeleteMsg.getParent();
        //get the textview containing receiver username from the view on which delete button is clicked
        TextView textviewReceiver = listviewRow.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgReceiverUsername);
        //get the textview containing timestamp value from the view on which delete button is clicked
        TextView textTimestamp = listviewRow.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgSentTime);
        //get the values of message receiver username and timestamp
        //timestamp value will be used to determine which message to delete
        //from database
        String receiverUsername = textviewReceiver.getText().toString();
        String timestamp = textTimestamp.getText().toString();
        //call delSentMsg() method in SentMessages Fragment using SentMessages Fragment
        //instance passed in the constructor of this class
        sentMsgsFragment.deleteSentMsg(receiverUsername, timestamp);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder{
        public TextView datetimeText;
        public TextView messageText;
        public TextView receiverUsernameText;
    }
}
```

## Question

I think the problem is that i am not able to correctly get the `ListView` row on which cross button is clicked on. How can i determine the row of `ListView` when a button is clicked on?

Comment: Please, add ListView Adapter code

Comment: @fisher3421 added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try making these changes to `CustomOutboxListAdapter` class.

In `CustomOutboxListAdapter` don't implement `View.OnClickListener`. Change it's class declaration from:

```
public class CustomOutboxListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener{
```

to:

```
public class CustomOutboxListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
```

And remove the `onClick` method inside:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
```

Replace `public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` with:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if(convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.listview_outbox_messages_row, null);

        //private inner class used to minimize the calls to "findViewById" method
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.datetimeText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgSentTime);
        holder.messageText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgText);
        holder.receiverUsernameText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgReceiverUsername);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }

    SentMessageTemplate stu = sentMsgsList.get(position);
    holder.datetimeText.setText(stu.getTimestamp());
    holder.messageText.setText(stu.getMessageContent());
    holder.receiverUsernameText.setText(stu.getMsgReceiver());


    // use local variable so it is always referenced correctly
    Button deleteBtn = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_deleteMsg_SMF);
    // Cache row position inside the button using `setTag`
    deleteBtn.setTag(position); 

    // Attach the click event handler
    deleteBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int position = (Integer) view.getTag();

            // Access the row position here to get the correct data item
            SentMessageTemplate sentMessageTemplate = getItem(position);

            String receiverUsername = sentMessageTemplate.getTimestamp();
            String timestamp = sentMessageTemplate.getMsgReceiver();

            sentMsgsFragment.deleteSentMsg(receiverUsername, timestamp);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

Just delete the member variable `private Button btnDeleteMsg;` as not used anymore.

Also for `getItemId(int i)` implementation, I think it should be something like:

```
@Override
public long getItemId( int position ) {
    return this.sentMsgsList.get(position).getId();
}
```

Then in `SentMessageTemplate` class, it should implement:

```
public int getId() {
    // return unique ID for object
    ....
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response, i was going to try the solution you suggested but i am a little confused about `getID` method that _returns unique ID for each object_. I haven't set any unique id for each instance of `SentMessageTemplate` class so how can i set a unique ID for each instance of `SentMessageTemplate`.

Comment: Then for `getId (int position)` , just stick back to your previous implementation which return `position`. Feel free to try out the rest of the code to see whether it helps, good luck!

Comment: overriding `onClick()` method inside `getView` method solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The bug is that you call `btnDeleteMsg.setOnClickListener(this);` only when adapter creates a new view for `ListView`. It happens only when app starts, after that ListView reuse views and doesn't call `btnDeleteMsg.setOnClickListener(this);`. So to resolve your issues you should move this line below  `holder.receiverUsernameText.setText(stu.getMsgReceiver());`

It will be like below

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inf = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inf.inflate(R.layout.listview_outbox_messages_row, null);

            //private inner class used to minimize the calls to "findViewById" method
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.datetimeText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgSentTime);
            holder.messageText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgText);
            holder.receiverUsernameText = convertView.findViewById(R.id.outbox_msgReceiverUsername);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }
        else {
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        }

        SentMessageTemplate stu = sentMsgsList.get(position);
        holder.datetimeText.setText(stu.getTimestamp());
        holder.messageText.setText(stu.getMessageContent());
        holder.receiverUsernameText.setText(stu.getMsgReceiver());
        //click listener for delete button
        btnDeleteMsg = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btn_deleteMsg_SMF);
        btnDeleteMsg.setOnClickListener(this);


        return convertView;
    }
```

Comment: thankyou for your response, I have tried this solution but the problem is still the same.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand the question BUT:

You can set IDs by calling setId on a View. Give your rows unique numbers. Then retrieve the IDs using getId in the onClick function to know which row was clicked so you can delete it. This is better than using Timestamp as they might coincidentally overlap, whereas you can make sure the IDs are all different.